# R correlation score calculation

Tags: r

My dataset contains information such as `feedbackDate` and Subcategory(issue) and location (6 months data). The temporal calculation was by cross tabulating the subcategory of issues with their `feebackDate`s and then calculating Pearson correlation score for every pair of cross tabulated issues. See the code below

```
#weekly correlation
require(ISOweek)
datacfs_date$FeedbackWeek <- ISOweek(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate)
raw_timecor_matrix <- table(datacfs_date$SubCategory, datacfs_date$FeedbackWeek)
raw_timecor_matrix <- t(raw_timecor_matrix)
timecor_matrix <- cor(raw_timecor_matrix)

#Invert correlation to get distance matrix
inverse_tcc <- 1-timecor_matrix
```

Now the question is how do I calculate this on biweekly and monthly basis instead of weekly correlation of six months data.

Comment: Providing actual or sample data would increase your chances of getting an answer
(you could give the results of `dput(datacfs_date)` or `dput(head(datacfs_date))`,
as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just make your labels, e.g.

```
datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth<-paste0(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),"-M",month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate))

datacfs_date$FeedbackBiWeek<-paste0(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),"-W",(ceiling(week(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate)/2)*2)-1,":",(ceiling(week(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate)/2)*2))
```

and correlate on those

Comment: if i want to calculate 3 days (correlation of 3 days,weekly,biweely,months) as well..how do i do that?

Comment: Getting an error message > datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth<-paste0(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),"-M",month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate))
Error in eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "paste0"